# jQuery draggable and revert with delay

Tags: jquery, draggable, delay, revert

I am trying to add a delay between when the user drags and drops the div, and when the div reverts back.

revertDuration controls the speed of the div reverting back, I want a delay before this happens.

I am quite unfamiliar with jQuery, spending too much time trying to work this out and it seems like it should be pretty straight-forward.

Here the jQuery:
`$( "#draggable" ).draggable({  revert: true , revertDuration: 1000 });`

and here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/YxBP9/54/

thank you very much

-e

Comment: Yes use revertDuration, what is the issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, let me clarify,
The delay I want is in between where the user drops the element, and when the revert function starts operating. The revertDuration controls the speed of when the div starts moving back, I want a delay before this is called. Any help is much appreciated..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not simple as it seems.

The only way I found is to use a function in the `revert` option and than use jQuery `delay` to wait your time, dealy was build up for other purposes (queue and animation) but in this case is working fine.

Code:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    revert: function () {
        $(this).delay(5000);
        return true
    },
    revertDuration: 1000
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/qGTF5/

Comment: Hey this works well, except during the delay(5000), you are unable to move the letter again.

Is there a work-around to keep the letters still moveable, but the initial delay still counting?